# Give List component specific data to display

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin

I am using `react-admin` framework (3.2). I have an object that stores entities that are filtered by expiration. I would like to display these entities in `List`. So far I have tried to create fake props to replicate the `List` component.

```
let fakeProps = {
            basePath: basePath,
            hasCreate: false,
            hasEdit: false,
            hasList: true,
            hasShow: false,
            history: {},
            location: { pathname: "/", search: "", hash: "", state: undefined },
            match: { path: "/", url: "/", isExact: true, params: {} },
            options: {},
            permissions: null,
            resource: resource,
            perPage: 30,
            actions: null,
            data: this.state.filteredList
        }
```

And then I return my list with props:

```
<List {...fakeProps}>
   <Datagrid>
      <TextField source='_id' />
   </Datagrid>
</List>
```

But I am only getting every entity. I need to display entities that are stored in `this.state.filteredList`.

Any ideas how can I do this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replicate the UI of `List` component use `ListController` and `ListView`.

```
<ListController {...fakeProps}>
  {({ data, ...controllerProps }) =>
    return <ListView data={yourData} {...fakeProps} {...controllerProps}>
    
    </ListView>
  }
</ListController>
```

It is also possible that you will have to transform the format of data that you are putting into the `ListView` using `reduce`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Also you might have to give `ListView` more custom props, just check the errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, it's key to note this explanation from react-admin

> The **List** view displays a list of records fetched from the API.
> The entry point for this view is the `<List>` component, which takes care of fetching the data.
> Then, it passes the data to an iterator view - usually `<Datagrid>`, which then delegates the rendering of each record property to  components.

Therefore, filtering is made at the `<List>` as you've done.
But the list has special props to support you in that.

To set default values to filters, you can pass an object literal as the `filterDefaultValues` prop of the `<List>` element.

```js
<List
  {...props}
  // entities that are filtered by expiration
  filterDefaultValues={{ is_expired: true }}
>
  <StyledTabbedDatagrid />
</List>
```